# How to express concisely the circular concept of a beginning and future simultaneously?

Tags: description

There are many movies/books which have an ending that is the foundation for the beginning of the story, an example is Terry Pratchett's book *Pyramids.* In a way these stories become trapped in a repeating circular process.

How can these types of stories be classified?
What term is used for this type of dependency?

Comment: How about *cyclic story*?

Comment: @Jubobs, It would be good to bring the essence of dependency, not just the repeating effect. Things can repeat without the end tying with the beginning necessarily.

Comment: I just thought of something: an *ouroborean story*, after the fabled snake [Ouroboros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros), who eats its own tail.

Comment: @Jubobs, very very good construction!!! worthy of an imagination badge!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I propose **ouroborean story**, after the fabled snake [Ouroboros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros), who ends up eating its own tail.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the apt mythological reference, although in practice I'd go with an established usage like _stable time loop._

Answer (score 3):

The TV Tropes jargon for this kind of story is [**stable time loop.**](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StableTimeLoop) They list Pratchett's *Pyramids* as an example of the trope. The concept of a stable time loop as ontological paradox is called the [bootstrap paradox,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_paradox) after a Robert A. Heinlein story of this nature.

Answer (score 1):

The cinematic or literary device of placing the ending at the beginning of a film or novel is called [flash-forward](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flash-forward).

It places an ineluctable, fixed point in the viewer's (or reader's) mind.

(To Jubobs's point, this phrase describes the fixed point, but is less about the story classification.)

Comment: As you wrote, *flash-forward* is a mere cinematographic or literary device. It says nothing about the story being cyclic, for lack of a better word. Take the movies Irreversible and Memento as examples: they both deliver the story in reverse chronological order, but that does not make the story itself cyclic in any way.

Comment: @Jubobs yes, I agree. Flash-forward doesn't describe the nature of the plot or the story classification. One wouldn't use Mary Shelley's *foreshadowing* to describe the plot of *Frankenstein*. But one might point to her use of the device of foreshadowing to better describe the novel. (I might classify hers as a novel that uses extensive foreshadowing. Similarly, the OP might classify his stories as science fiction/fantasy that uses flash-forwards.

Comment: *Memento* seems fairly unique in its presentation. (I haven't watched *Irreversible*.) One might classify it as a tragedy in reverse chronological order.